# How do I prevent ASP.NET MVC from caching invalid data in my View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, validation

I have a situation that I can't seem to find any help on. I looked through many questions on here, but can't seem to find anybody that has asked (or answered) my specific question. Here it is:

Assume I have 2 categories:

- Paper (id: 1)
- Plastic (id: 2)

The user clicks on `Paper`, change the name to `Plastic`, and click 'Submit'.

Inside my controller I discover that there is a already a category named `Plastic` so I re-sends the page to the user with a friendly message.

The problem arises when the user decides to ***not*** change the value, and instead navigate away from the page. They do some other things and then click on `Paper` again to change it's name. Only this time they actually see the name `Plastic` in the textbox!?

I have this problem on all of my controllers when I reject invalid form data. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: This can be server or browser. You need to debug your action and make sure that "Plastic" is not sent by the server in either ViewData/Model or in ModelState[name].Value.

Comment: Perfect! I fixed the problem by registering the Castle Windsor Lifestyle Module and set the components lifestyle="PerWebRequest". Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to answer this question myself to indicate my question was answered by [queen3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119224/queen3) in a comment. I discovered that the value was coming back from my LinqToSql with the invalid value.

The way that I fixed the issue was by registering the Castle Windsor `PerWebRequestLifestyleModule` http module like so:

```
<httpModule>
 <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.MicroKernel" />
 ...
</httpModule>
```

Then I went to each component and set the lifestyle to `PerWebRequest` like so:

```
<component 
    id="..."
    service="..."
    type="..."
    lifestyle="PerWebRequest">

    ...

  </component>
```

Thanks [queen3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119224/queen3)!